# editText.setError no funciona como debería?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, spinner, edittext

El problema es que quiero hacer una validacion de varios campos editText y Spinner. cuando no cumplen con una condición, se muestra el icono de error sobre el campo a la derecha (el de default). y un mensaje (este ultimo solo se muestra cuando el campo tiene el foco), para ello utilizo el método:
`myEditText.setError("mensaje")` esto me funciono bien en un proyecto, pero ahora, en uno nuevo, el icono simplemente no se muestra, el mensaje si.

mis editText están dentro de un TextInputLayout, descubrí que si lo quito, entonces es posible ver el icono, al principio pensé que a lo mejor el icono quedaba oculto bajo el input o fuera de pantalla, pero moviendo los campos y sus tamaños varias veces, descubrí que no.

No puedo usar el error del TextInputLayout porque este no borra el mensaje automáticamente cuando el campo recibe el foco.

un ejemplo de uno de mis edit text:

```
<!--Numero-->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tilNumero"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/editor_text">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/txtNumero"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                            android:background="#00000000"
                            android:hint="Numero:"
                            android:inputType="number" />

                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                        android:paddingTop="15dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_black_24dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>
```

En el java:

```
if(this.txtNumero.getText().toString().equals("") ) {
        if(this.txtNumero.getText().toString().equals(""))
            mensaje="Este campo es requerido";

        this.txtNumero.setError(mensaje);
        //this.txtNumero.setFocusable(true);
        respuesta = false;
    }
```

No se si tenga algo que ver las versiones de android, funciona en el proyecto con la targetedVersion=25, en el proyecto actual tiene la targetedVersion=26
la minVersion=19 para ambos

Comment: espero mi respuesta te ayude :)

Answer (score 1):

Cuando usas `.setError` debes primero declarar tus variables `null`, para que cuando recorra de nuevo las condiciones están se eliminen al presionar el botón o realizar otra acción.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tilNumero"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        app:errorEnabled="true" // activas el mensaje de error
                        android:background="@drawable/editor_text">
```

***tilNumero es el id de tu TextInputLayout***

Para utilizar el `setError` de tu `TextInputLayout` :

```
    public void validar(){
    tilNumero.setError(null)
    tilNumero.clearFocus();

    if(txtNumero.length()==0) { // los números se validan con .length 

       tilNumero.setError("No puede dejar este campo vació")
       tilNumero..requestFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) // con esto abres el teclado despues de ubicar el foco en tu editText
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(txtNumero, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }



}
```

Para terminar llamas a `validar()` para utilizarla.

Por otra parte para validar tu `spinner`puedes usar una forma personalizada para tener el mismo efecto del `setError` ya que este control no lo incluye por defecto o simplemente usar un `Toast`. Si quieres la forma mas larga hazme saber y lo añado para no hacer la respuesta muy larga.

Comment: Felix, es txtNumero.getText().length() en lugar de solo txtNumero.length, txtNumero es un EditText :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar una opción que siempre sirve a la hora de validar en Android:

```
package com.tuaplicacion;

public class TuActivity{

    EditText email, password;
    Button login_button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tuactivity);

        email = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.password);
        login_button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        email.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(email));
        password.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(password));

        password.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    attempLogin(view);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                attempLogin(view);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    //Set focus to input
    private void requestFocus(View view) {
        if (view.requestFocus()) {
            getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    // Validating email
    private boolean validateEmail() {
        String email_check = email.getText().toString().trim();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email_check)) {
            email.setError("El email no puede estar vacío");
            requestFocus(email);
            return false;
        } else {
            email.setError(null);
        }

        return true;
    }

    // Validating password
    private boolean validatePassword() {
        String password_check = password.getText().toString().trim();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password_check)) {
            email.setError("La contraseña no puede estar vacía");
            requestFocus(password);
            return false;
        } else {
            email.setError(null);
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void attempLogin(View view) {
        if (!validateEmail()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!validatePassword()) {
            return;
        }

        Login(view);
    }

    public void Login(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Ha iniciado Sesión", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private View view;

        private MyTextWatcher(View view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            return;
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            return;
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.email:
                    validateEmail();
                    break;
                case R.id.password:
                    validatePassword();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Espero que te ayude!

Comment: Es bueno ver tus contribuciones!, solo como comentario, el código del usuario muestra elementos diferentes por lo tanto este código tal vez no le será de utilidad, te recomiendo agregues una explicación, revisar [ask]

Answer (score -1):

Para ver el error usando TextInputLayout tienes que habilitar los mensajes de errores, lo puedes hacer así desde xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
   android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:errorEnabled="true">
```

O desde código:

```
 textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
```

Con esto evitarás que el TextInputLayout no se redimensione y se muestre el mensaje de error.

Comment: Es que precisamente, lo que quiero es evitar usar el setError del TextInputLayout, porque no funciona como quiero; es el setError del Edit Text el que me interesa. el setErrorEnabled si lo active cuando probé el til, pero ese método no existe para EditText

Comment: @diegoveloper El OP desea evitar usar el setError del TextInputLayout, por  lo tanto no aplica lo que agregas en tu respuesta.